Criterion for normality of a subgroup
Let $G$ be a group. It is well-known that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ for every subgroup of $H$ of $G$, where $NH:=\{nh \ |\ n\in N,h\in H\}$. Note that $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $NH=HN$.
My question is, is the converse true? More precisely, suppose that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $NH$ is a also a subgroup of $G$ for every subgroup $H$ of $G$. Can we conclude that $N$ is normal?
One may even ask a stronger question that if $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ for every subgroup $H$ which is a conjugate of $N$ (i.e., $H=gNg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$), then must $N$ be normal?
Clearly, the `stronger' question, which is motivated by looking at $S_3$, has a positive answer if $G$ is finite and $N$ a Sylow subgroup of $G$. One is welcome to assume that $G$ is finite if that makes any difference in the answer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinormal_subgroup

Excellent, thank you!
